# LS_COLORS for 256-color terminal

Tags: terminal, ls, colors, escape-characters

I thought ls colors are defined as

`<file_type>=[<bg(40-47)>];<font_spec(0:5)>;<font_color(30-37)>`

but, I recently found [this](https://github.com/seebi/dircolors-solarized/blob/master/dircolors.256dark) where there are more colors and colors are specified as, e.g.:

```
.tar    00;38;5;61
```

for a 256-color terminal.

What does this definition mean?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The argument to a `LS_COLORS` directive is a string that is written to the terminal as part of an escape sequence. When displaying a file name, `ls` writes `\e[`, then the string associated with the file type, then `m`, then the file name, then `\e[0m` (where `\e` represents an escape character). This is the escape sequence that tells xterm and compatible terminals (which is most of them nowadays) to change colors and other text attributes (`CSI Pm m` in the [documentation](http://invisible-island.net/xterm/ctlseqs/ctlseqs.html#h2-Functions-using-CSI-_-ordered-by-the-final-character_s_). `ls` doesn't care what the sequence of characters means or how many semicolons it contains.

Old terminals only supported 8 foreground colors, designated by the numbers 30 through 37. Terminals that support more colors use the escape sequence `\e[38;5;Psm` where *Ps* is a color number, or `\e[38;2;Pr;Pg;Pbm` where *Pr*, *Pg*, *Pb* are RGB values. These can be combined with other attributes, e.g. `\e38;5;61;1m` or `\e38;2;95;95;175;1m` for bold slate blue text.

Comment: This is unfortunately undocumented by `dircolors`, so that I spent some time looking at the `ls` source to see what I could do, until I found out that this was already possible. I've reported a bug, so that this could be documented: https://debbugs.gnu.org/cgi/bugreport.cgi?bug=33915